# rsync over ssh -A not working and getting permission denied

Tags: php, drupal-8

i am able to do the following,

```
ssh -A <host>
rsync -r -h --stats source_host:folder/file desstination_folder
```

but same thing if i want to do with the php i am getting permission denied.

```
ssh -A <host>
$cmd = 'rsync -r -h --stats source_host:folder/file destinat_folder';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

To be more detailed, i am trying execute this shell_exec command from drush custom command.

Comment: I think the user under which php is executed does not have permissions to execute rsync and/or ssh. To test, write up a shell script that does all this. put it in a binaries directory that the php server has permissions on or assign a group that has permissions to the script. Than try to call the script from where you need to.... Also: assign permissions to server to allow usage of rsync & ssh if that is an option

Comment: Second thought: folder you want to write to is outside of the server root and not writable by the server. Give server permissions to write to that folder or SymLink it?

Comment: i am getting Permission denied (publickey). so it is not related to destination write permissions.

Comment: that means your ssh keys are not set up right yet. You should maybe back up and renew your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Regenerate your key or re-add your public key to the authorized_keys file of the target user. Or check your sshd.conf? If you google your (publickey) error a lot will come up that might help

Comment: the ssh keys are properly working with the first set of commands.

Comment: are your ssh keys set-up with or without a password?

Comment: you need to add rsa_pub.key from server 1 into authorizekey on server 2